# Keyboard does not dismiss interactively

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard

On an iOS app, I have the following view structure:
UIViewController > UIView > UIScrollView > UITextView

The UIScrollView has the "Dismiss Interactively" setting. When I tap on the UITextView, the keyboard pops-up properly. However I now try to gradually dismiss the keyboard by slowly swiping my finger down, but nothing happens.

Did I forget anything in my configuration ?

[Example project](http://www.petits-suisses.ch/essaiScroll.zip)

Comment: Can you share a simple example?

Comment: `Dismiss on Drag` should be enabled.

Comment: Dismiss on drag or interactively don't change anything.

Comment: Regarding example, not sure what you mean. Simply create a new single-view project, in InterfaceBuilder add a full-screen UIScrollView, configure it in with dismiss interactively, and a UITextView inside. Launch your app, click on the UITextView, the keyboard will open, now try to bring it down, it won't work.

Comment: To the person who set me -1, thanks to explain why and what I should have done differently

Comment: XCode project added to issue description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was linked to the fact that the scrollView contents were shorter than the screen size.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7, you can use

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
```

The keyboard follows the dragging touch offscreen and can be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss.

Comment: Thanks. But as explained in my description, interactive is already set.